# Cgs,Cgd capacitor in Mosfet/ problem with measurement unit

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, theory

I am a little confused with this problem.

I would like to ask if I have a Mosfet(in saturation)and I have find that Cgs=16fF and Coverlap = 0.5fF/um(this is given in the description of the exercise), how I can calculate the Cgstotal = Cgs + Coverlap and the Cgd = 0 + Coveralp?

The measurement units for the first equation shouldn't have been the same?Also in the second equation for Cgd, units is F/m but I think should be only Farad(F).

Can anyone help I have no idea how I can solve this problem.

Comment: You already know Cgs, you do not know Coverlap **but** it is given in x fF/um  so that means you need some length or width. When would Coverlap double ? If I doubled the L or W of the MOS ??

Comment: Τhank you  Bimpelrekkie for your response.But I know the value of Cov=0.5fF/um.The problem is only with the measurement units and not with the numerical values as they are known

Comment: Read my comment again and expecially: *you need some length or width*

Comment: Sorry Bimpelrekkie but I can understand your thought.You wrote me that "you do not know Coverlap" but I wrote you in the description  that Coverlap = 0.5fF/um.

Comment: Coverlap cannot be 0.5 fF/um as that is Capacitance **per length**. So you need the **width** of the MOSFET to know Coverlap. If the MOSFET has a W/L of 10um/1um then that Coverlap is 10 um x 0.5 fF/um = 5 fF. If the assignment shows no length then it is useless to specify Coverlap in fF/um.

Comment: Thank you very much  Bimpelrekkie now I understand your thoughts.Also description gives that μnCox=200uA/V, λ=1/(5V), -Vtp=Vtn=0.5V, VDD=2V,
Lmin=0.5um, Cox=5fF/um, Col=0.5fF/um,W/L=20.Can this data help you to find the solution?The Cgs I had calculate from this equation Cgs=2/3*W*L*Cox=  2/3(W/L)*(Lmin) ^2 *Cox =16fF so now Cgstotal =Cgs + Coverlap

Comment: *Can this data help you to find the solution?* No, it will help **you** find the solution. L is there and W/L is there so you do the maths !

Comment: Thanks Bimpelrekkie.So in this case Coverlap = W*Coverlap....and I can find that W=10um so Coverlap = 10um*0.5fF/um = 5fF?